# Triggering a shiny alert by an input value in a Shiny Markdown document

Tags: r, shiny

I would like a `shinyalert` warning to appear when the user has no selections made on an input (i.e. when the length of `input$vals` equals zero. However, the code below is not working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

````
---
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document
---

```{r echo = F, message = F, warning = F, error = F}
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(tidyverse)

selectInput("vals", "Select", choices = c("a", "b"),
            multiple = T, selected = "a")

observeEvent(input$vals, {
  if(input$vals %>% length == 0) {
    shinyalert("Select At Least One")
  }
})
```
````

Comment: `observeEvent` is a server side function, it can be used in an app or a dashboard.but not in a static markdown document. You can instead use HTML/javascript code

Comment: I actually was able to use it in a Markdown file. See example here close to the bottom of the page: https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert

As a heads up, may need to install most recent version of shinyalerts to run this: devtools::install_github("daattali/shinyalert")

That doesn't appear to be the issue, what's not working for me is the check on the length of the input triggering the alert.

Comment: my bad, it is actually a dynamic markdown document. The issue is that `observeEvent` is not triggered when `input$val` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger `observeEvent()` even when input is NULL, you can set its `ignoreNULL` parameter to `FALSE` (default `TRUE`).
It is then better to set its `ignoreInit` parameter to `TRUE` (default `FALSE`), to prevent the trigger before the "a" element is selected.

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo = F, message = F, warning = F, error = F}
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(tidyverse)

selectInput("vals", "Select", choices = c("a", "b"),
            multiple = T, selected = "a")

observeEvent(input$vals, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
  if(input$vals %>% length == 0) {
    shinyalert("Select At Least One")
  }
})
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can check on the length of the input with is.null

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  selectInput("vals", "Select", choices = c("a", "b"),
              multiple = T, selected = "a") 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$vals)){
      shinyalert('Select At Least One')}
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```